# Changing array value inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to javascript/React with less than 5 months exp so a lot of mistakes, what I'm trying to achieve is...

when a user clicks a button, the country value will change and I want to do something like this.

```
if (country === "Singapore") {   setTeams(sg.items)  } else {   setTeams(my.items) }
```

but I'm unable to achieve it inside useEffect hook or my approach is wrong.

```
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("Singapore")

  const sg = data.sgteamlist
  const my = data.myteamlist

  useEffect(() => {
    setTeams(sg.items)
  }, [])

  const [teams, setTeams] = useState([])
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
  const [teamsPerPage] = useState(5)

  // Get current teams
  const indexOfLastTeam = currentPage * teamsPerPage
  const indexOfFirstTeam = indexOfLastTeam - teamsPerPage
  const currentTeams = teams.slice(indexOfFirstTeam, indexOfLastTeam)
  const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber)

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Box px="7.5%" color="white.50" pb="20rem">
        <SEO title="About" />
        <Helmet bodyAttributes={{ class: "about-page" }} />
        <TeamGrid teams={currentTeams} />
        <ButtonToggler onClick={() => setCountry("Singapore")}>
          Singapore
        </ButtonToggler>
        <ButtonToggler onClick={() => setCountry("Malaysia")}>
          Malaysia
        </ButtonToggler>
        <Pagination
          teamsPerPage={teamsPerPage}
          totalTeams={teams.length}
          paginate={paginate}
        />
      </Box>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default AboutPage
```

I want to change the setTeams array based on the value of the country.

Comment: You have to define the state and setTeams before you can use it in useEffect. Move your useEffect down, so that you're calling it after you create all your states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `country` as a dependency to your effect. The dependency array will run your effect every time the variable is different, based on shallow checking.

Also you should move your useEffect after the definition of the state variable `teams`.

```
const [teams, setTeams] = useState(sg.items);

useEffect(() => {
  if(country === 'Singapore') {
    setTeams(sg.items)
  } else {
    setTeams(my.items)
  },
}, [country])
```

Comment: OMG! it's work... thank you, sir!! been bugging me for a few hours now..